# Add text to JavaScript via input tag

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This is kind of unusual, but is there anyway to add text into JavaScript via the input tag?

For instance,

```
 <input type="text" id="example" />
```

and let's say the JavaScript is

```
function show_alert()
{
alert("The text entered in #example will show up here");
}
```

Is this anyway possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In straight Javascript (i.e. no libraries), you can use:

```
var exampleValue = document.getElementById('example').value;
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/H6bKL/

But if you're going to do much of this, and especially if you want to get values from a variety of form elements, you'd do yourself a favor using jQuery or another library with good DOM access functions.